# how to get append textbox name from main blade view and insert into controller in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I want to get this  textbox name in form and then insert to controller,it is appending but form not sending the append textbox name and value to controller.
the bellow is my from which is popup by button the form include in model.

```
    <script>

            $("#cont").on('click', function () {
                var fav = [];
                var checko = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
                for (var i = 0; i < checko.length; i++) {
                $('.someo').append('<input type="text" name="numberofvehicle[]" class="form-control" value="' + fav.push($(this).val()) + '"/>');

                }

            });

    </script>







     <form  action="{{url('add_to_container')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
          <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y: auto;border: 0px solid black;">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="container">Chose Container</label>
          <br>
<select  style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" name="container">
                                                               @foreach(App\container::all() as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->booking_number}}</option>
 @endforeach
    </select>
               </div>
              </div>
     <div class="form-group someo" id="som">
     </div>



                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <div style="">

                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                                                                    style="align-content: center; padding-left: 11px;padding-right: 11px;">
                                                                Change Container Status
                                                            </button>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                Cancel
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
```

Comment: Khana, please provide some more details on this, the question is still not clear.

Comment: This is my form and i want to append the above textbox this form div tag it is showing the textbox but the form not inserting the append textbox name and value .

Comment: I think I understood your problem. You mean that you are adding a field with jQuery to your form and when you click on submit, you cannot retrieve values for those added fields in your controller method, right?

Answer (score 0):

When you add new fields dynamically with JavaScript/jQuery in your form, those fields, and their values will not be sent with your post request when you click the form submit button.

You can handle form submit with jQuery and send a post request with your form's serialized data as shown below:

```
$('#formId').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('/add_to_container', formData);
});
```